# Associated elements on Euclidean Domains

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, euclidean-domain

I am trying to solve a problem about Euclidean Domain. The problem is:

> Let $R$ be an Euclidean Domain, $a,b \in R-\{0\}, a|b$ and $d(a)=d(b)$. Show that $a$ and $b$ are associates.

I am trying to show it by showing that $b|a$. The idea is to get a contradiction if we suppose $b$ does not divide $a$. However, the definition of Euclidean Domain that I am working does not involve the $d-$inequality, that is, if $a,b \in R-\{0\}$ then $d(a) \leqslant d(ab)$. I know that there exist a way to show that we can always consider this inequality, but my question is: can someone give me a hint about how to solve it without using this inequality?

There are another question about similar thinks here, but I did not find any of them talking about my specific question and this is why I am asking about it. If there is another question regarding this, please, let me know.

Thank you so much everyone!

Comment: Is $d$ euclidean valuation function

Comment: Yes, it is. But in my definition that inequality does not need to hold.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't true without assuming the $d$-inequality.  For instance, let $R=\mathbb{Z}$ and define $d(a)=a$ if $a>0$ and $d(a)=-2a$ if $a<0$.  Then you still have division with remainder for this $d$, since you can always choose your remainder to be nonnegative.  But $a=-2$ and $b=4$ satisfy $a\mid b$ and $d(a)=d(b)$ and are not associates.

Comment: is there any easy way to prove that this $d-$inequality always holds?

Comment: Under what assumptions?  It's not true for a general Euclidean domain (if you don't include it in the definition).

Comment: My complete definition is: A Euclidean Domain is an ID for which there is a function $d:R-\{0\} \to \mathbb{N}$ such that if $a,b \in R$ and $b$ is not zero then there exists $q,r \in R$ such that $a=qb+r$ with either $d(r)<d(b)$ or $r=0.$ :)

Comment: Right, so with that definition the $d$-inequality does _not_ always hold, nor does the statement of the problem you are trying to solve.  My answer gives a counterexample.

Comment: thank you for your help. Can you give a loot at this document http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/ringtheory/euclideanrk.pdf specifically at the Theorem 2.1. and the beginning of the next section. Here he is proving that we can always assume that the $d-$ inequality holds. I am confused. haha

Comment: What he is saying is that you can choose a _different_ $d$ for which the $d$-inequality holds.  That is, if $(R,d)$ is a euclidean domain by your definition, you can define a different function $\tilde{d}:R\to\mathbb{N}$ such that $(R,\tilde{d})$ is still a euclidean domain and $\tilde{d}$ satisfies the inequality.

Comment: Nice. But, look at the beggining of section 3. He said, Let $R$ an Euclidean Domain. We may assume that our function $d$ satisfy the $d-$inequality. Is it wrong?

Comment: What he means by that is that you can choose $d$ such that it satisfies the $d$-inequality.  So if you are proving statements that only involve $R$ and not $d$, you can assume $d$ satisfies the $d$-inequality.

Comment: But what is the utility of assuming $d$ satisfying the $d-$inequality in statements that does not involves $d$?

Comment: Because you use the $d$-inequality in the process of proving those statements.